# website elements get mixed up when browser gets readjusted

Tags: html, css

I wrote a website for a travel based start up. It is a static website, not a responsive website. The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hs7w51t0/).
**`Code:`**

```
<div id="mainDiv" class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="plc">
                <h1><a href="#"></a></h1>
                <nav>
                    <div id="navPos">
                        <div style="position: relative;right: 113px;">Register</div>
                        <div style="position: absolute;right: 255px;top: 37px;">Login</div>
                        <div style="position: absolute;top: 38px;right: 123px;">Market</div>    
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body" class="container-fluid">
            <div id="container">
                <div id="overlay"></div>
                <div id="menu"></div>
                <div id="info">Fill your information here</div>
                <div id="formPos"></div>
                <div id="or">OR</div>
                <div id="fbReg">
                    <img src="images/fbOne.png" id="fbIcon">
                    <div id="fbPos">Register with Facebook</div>
                </div>
                <div id="gReg">
                    <img src="images/gPlus.jpg" id="gIcon">
                    <div id="gPos">Register with Google</div>
                </div>
                <div id="cliPos">
                    <img src="images/Bistip-in-media.png" id="imgCli">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="aboutUs">
                About Us
            </div>
            <div id="aboutList">
                <ul>
                    <li>About us</li>
                    <li>Media reviews</li>
                    <li>Bistip guide</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="accountInformation">
                Account Information 
            </div>
            <div id="accountList">
                <ul>
                    <li>How to login</li>
                    <li>Create an account</li>
                    <li>Logout</li>
                    <li>Join us</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="marketInformation">
                Market Information  
            </div>
            <div id="marketList">
                <ul>
                    <li>Shop</li>
                    <li>Shipping</li>
                    <li>My connection</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Website in full screen browser appears like this:

[image: img1]
[image: img2]
Browser is resized like this:
[image: img3]
You can see that elements are mixed up. How can I fix this?

Comment: use media query..or bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using position absolute in some elements.
You could try to use bootstrap.css and take off all the positions that you are using.

Comment: sorry but not agree with you. I can use position absolute while making my site responsive. Please only provide answer with level and not leading to wrong direction.

Comment: Sorry @Ajay, but I'm not saying that you can't use absolute.

-Leo the Lion
I just said that he used that in a few arguments and should check it.
About my real answer was the same as yours. "You could try to use bootstrap" please don't be hypocrite.

Comment: what if I use relative position?

Comment: no m not being hypocrite but by reading your answer it look like misplace is because position so i said that.hope you will understand.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni, no its not if you will remove then your issue will be resolved but you have to type css in media queries for all element whom you wants to set up for different different version.

Comment: Hi @Ajax I will just explain what I'm used to do.
I wouldnt create <div> for each item in the menu,for this you could use a List element like <ul><li> This would help in the menu (Login, Register and market)

you don't need position or left,right, you could do that like this http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal

for the form and facebook, I would try something like http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

All you need is actually only divs, floats, margin and padding, no left, right position

But if you want you can use them if you like.

Comment: and Leo is right, if you want a responsive website you need to use media query

There is one example here
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

What a "@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {"

does, is by the website being 300 width, it will load a different style